# How to create an event with state update (by getDerivedStateFromProps)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-component

I am trying to change `componentWillReceiveProps` method to static `getDerivedStateFromProps` and can't figure out how to use the keyword this inside the `getDerivedStateFromProps` function.

Originally, I wanted to use `this.props.history.push()` inside the `getDerivedStateFromProps` but could not figure out how.
I then tried returning state (as `getDerivedStateFromProps` is supposed to do) and could not create an event with it. A brief look at the code will make my question more comprehensible.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if(nextProps.passwordResetResult.message==="Password reset 
      Successfully")
    {
      alert("Password reset successfully please login again");
         this.props.history.push('/home')
    }
   }
```

I know I am supposed to return state at the end; but I didn't find it useful for my purpose, as don't understand how do I create an event which will be triggered on state change after return and then trigger `this.props.history.push()`.

Above code caused error

> this.props is undefined.

I understand I can't use `this` keyword inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`; am I correct in assuming that?

Comment: Take a look at [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDerviedStateFromProps` is a static function, so you can't access `this` from it, static functions are bound to the class itself and not the instance of the component. I believe its intentionally done this way to avoid side effects.

So Instead of using `this.history.push` you should use `nextProps.history.push` which you get in the lifecycle hook arguments.

But as for your use-case since you said you don't really need to return state, it means you don't really need derived state because you don't change internal state based on specific props. You should use `componentDidUpdate` instead for side-effects, see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops